# I can't connect to my FTP server using Filezila

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to connect to one of the servers using FileZila

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 182.176.65.31:25...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER pgl
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Response:    LANG EN*
Error:  Connection timed out after 60 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

while I've tested same account from a web based FTP client and it's working and then I tried an andriod FTP app and it worked too, it seems just FileZila isn't connecting, didn't try another desktop client as i prefer FileZia,

p.s: there is no problem with FileZila as i'm able to connect to other servers from the same application

Comment: What connection settings are you using, have you asked the server admin to confirm port number, etc.?

Comment: port 25 isn't ftp. If I remember, FileZilla lets you save how to connect, so you probably fat-fingered the port.  Most web ftp clients fake ftp by really using http.

Comment: port 25 is explicitly set as ftp port.